# Is management studio 2016 provides sql server 2016

Tags: database, sql-server

So I [**Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) and my question is does management studio provides any sql server 2016.

Currently I have sql server 2012 installed on my PC and when I try to open localhost from linked management studio I always open it as version 11.0.3156, but I can't find a way to open 13.0... version.If someone is wondering I'm opening the correct management studio.

In the article in msdn is written:

> The release number: 16.5.1
>
> The build number for this release:
> 13.0.16100.1

Comment: It sounds like you have SSMS 2012 not 2016 installed since your versions matches the 2013 version and not the 2016 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the DL for the SQL Management Studio it doesn't include any SQL Server components. It's merely able to connect to any previous version of MS SQL server. To check your installed version start the Management Studio and check the version displayed under Help » Info.

To upgrade your SQL server you would need some form of media for the SQL server files. You could use [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016) for example but you would have to make sure you have suitable licenses beforehand. Alternatively there should be some form of download available from within your TechNet or Volume Licensing portal.

Comment: Thanks I install sql server 2016, now everything is working properly !